# Handling internet connection R

Tags: r

I`m trying to download several stocks from google, but every time the connection stops, R stops the loop. How can I handle this problem?

```
stocks <- c(
  'MSFT',
  'GOOG',
   ...
)



for (symbol in stocks)
{
  stock_price <- getSymbols(symbol,src='google', from=startDate,to=endDate,auto.assign = FALSE)
  prices[,j] <- stock_price[,1]
  j <- j + 1


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the R manual "quantmod.pdf:

`If auto.assign=FALSE or env=NULL (as of 0.4-0) the data will be returned`
`from the call, and will require the user to assign the results himself.`
`Note that only one symbol at a time may be requested when auto assignment is disabled.`

You are trying to request more than one ticket symbol at a time with the `auto.assign` parameter set to `false` and this is not allowed.  However, you should be able to obtain all your symbols at once by adapting the following code:

```
data <- new.env()

getSymbols.extra(stocks, src = 'google', from = startDate, to = endDate, env = data, auto.assign = T)
plot(data$MSFT)
```

Pay careful attention to the [R manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf) for `getSymbols`

```
"Data is fetched through one of the available getSymbols methods and saved in the env specified - the .GloblEnv by default.
```

Comment: I think  that is wrong, as Filipe already uses `auto.assign=FALSE`.

Comment: I guess this doesn't help completely, because I would like to get all the data in only one object. This way I'm able to run loops/vectorized operations through all stocks with low effort